# Maximum of fraction with products of consecutive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Fix a positive integer $k\geq 2$. For positive integer $n\geq k$, define

$$f(n)=\frac{\left(n-\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}\rfloor}\right)\left(n-\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}\rfloor}-1\right)\cdots\left(n-\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}\rfloor-k+1}\right)}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}.$$ Note that $f(k)=0$ and $f(k+1)=\dfrac{1}{k+1}$.

Is it true that $f(n)<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq k$? From plotting some values it seems that the maximum is $\dfrac{k-1}{2k-1}$, which is attained for $$f(2k-1)=\dfrac{(2k-2)(2k-3)\cdots(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k-2)\cdots k}=\dfrac{k-1}{2k-1}<\dfrac12.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Put $m=\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$. Then 
$$f(n)=\prod_{l=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{m}{n-l}\right),$$
$$f(2k-1)=\prod_{l=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k-1-l}\right).$$

So it suffices to show that

$$1-\frac{m}{n-l}\le 1-\frac{1}{2k-l},$$

for every $l$. This inequality is equivalent to

$$n+l(m-1)\le (2k-1)m,$$

which holds because $n\le k(m+1)-1$ and $l\le k-1$.